# Is it possible in Node to read in a file an export its contents (without exporting asyncronly)?

Tags: node.js

**TLDR:** I want to read in a file's contents and then export a function which relies on those contents ... without making that exported function use promises or some other form of asynchronicity.

I'm trying to write an XML-validating module, and in order for it to do its thing I need to read in an XSD file.  However, this only needs to happen once at "load time", so ideally I'd rather not have other modules that use my function have to wait for a promise to resolve to get their results.  If I were using Webpack this would be easy, as I could use it's text file loader to bring in the XSD as if it were any other module ... but unfortunately I'm not.

In other words, currently I have to do (borderline pseudo-code):

```
module.exports.validate = () => 
   new Promise((resolve) =>
       fs.readFile(path, (file) => {
           // use file to validate, then:
           resolve(validationResult);
       }); 
   });
```

};

and instead I'd like to do:

```
fs.readFile(path, (file) => {
   module.exports.validate = myValidationFunction;
});
```

But the above doesn't work because you can't export from callbacks, so my question is, is there any other way to accomplish this?

The https://github.com/jonschlinkert/to-exports library seems to offer exactly this, so it seems like it's possible ... but it doesn't work for me :(

P.S. At worst I could literally wrap the contents of the file inside the template string characters, rename the file to be `.js`, and export it that way:

```
module.exports = `*XSD contents go here*`;
```

However, that seems very kludgy, so I'm hoping there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read a file synchronously, then use [`fs.readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options). It returns the contents of the file or throws an error.

Comment: The sad thing is I even knew those functions existed but I'd forgotten about them ... sometimes the obvious answer is staring you right in the face and you need a little SO to see it.  Thanks!